# Kafka: Producer threads get stuck

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, java-threads

I have an Apache Nifi workflow that streams data into Kafka. My Kafka cluster is made of 5 nodes that uses SSL for encryption.
When there is a lot of data that is going throw, my Kafka producer (PublishKafkaRecord) freeze and stop working. I have to restart the processor and I am getting Threads errors.
I am using Kafka Confluent 5.3.1.

I am seeing these errors in the Kafka logs:

```
ERROR Uncaught exception in scheduled task 'transactionalID-expiration' (Kafka.utils.Kafkascheduler)

Retrying leaderEpoch request for partitions XXX-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_LEADER_EPOCH (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)

Could not find offset index file corresponding to log file XXX/*.log recovering segment and rebuilding index files (kafka.log.Log)

ERROR when handing request: .... __transaction_state

ERROR TransactionMetadata (... ) failed: this should not happen (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMetadata)
```

I cannot pin point to the actual error.

How can I fix Threads being stuck in Kafka?

Comment: Is `__transaction_state` topic healthy?

Comment: how can I check this?

Comment: `kafka-topics --describe` is one way

Comment: In my 5 brokers clusters, the `__transaction_state` topic have 50 partitions and `Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,unclean.leader.election.enable=false,compression.type=uncompressed,cleanup.policy=compact,min.insync.replicas=2`

Comment: And if you look across all the partitions, the replica counts are all the same? Nothing missing? Otherwise, I assume NiFi has a configuration not to use a transactional producer, but it seems to be specifically complaining about this topic